# singular entity as a collection of subjects

Tags: grammatical-number

"If you are looking for a XYZ Residential Real Estate Attorney, the Law Offices of John Smith ***is*** here to help. "

The firm itself is called "the Law Offices of John Smith", so is it correct that it would be referred to as a singular entity like that?

Answer (score 1):

- Whether the name of the place or the firm is singular or plural, it must
  be treated as a singular entity.
- The capital "L" of "Law" calls attention to the fact that all five of the 
  words "Law Offices of John Smith" are to be treated as a single
  entity.

Comment: I disagree -- see my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

The name of a legal or commercial entity is not exempt from the convention of subject-verb agreement unless it is subsumed under another descriptor.

For instance, the following would be grammatically OK:

> If you are looking for an XYZ Residential Real Estate Attorney, the entity known as the Law Offices of John Smith is here to help".

This is permissible because the singular noun *entity* is now the subject of the main clause, with "the Law Offices of John Smith" having in effect been placed in parentheses.

The result is not very elegant from a stylistic point of view, but that's a different issue.

Comment: Do you have a source for this rule?