# Singular entity, plural name/nickname -- verb form?

Tags: verb-agreement

In writing about the National Archives, I got to wondering about subject-verb agreement.  The National Archives and Records Administration (NARA, often called simply The National Archives) is one entity, but when using the nickname, it would appear at first glance to be plural.

So, even though *Archives* is plural, because it is a single entity, does it still take a singular verb?

Note: I see on the NARA website, in the menu at the bottom, there is a link labelled *[What is the National Archives?](https://www.archives.gov/about)* so it would appear that they believe the nickname is singular.

Does it matter that the full name of the agency is the *National Archives and Records **Administration***?  When using the full name, I think it is clear that the verb should be singular (to match with the singular *administration*):

> The *National Archives and Records Administration* **is** the nation's record keeper.

I'm just not 100% certain about the situation when using the shortened nickname:

> The National Archives is the nation's record keeper.

I found a question *[singular entity as a collection of subjects](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/186319/singular-entity-as-a-collection-of-subjects)* that is similar, but there does not seem to have a definitive answer and does not have the same twist of the full name being obviously singular.

Comment: There have been many questions on the site which concern "singular or plural" as regards sports teams. You may find[this list](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=sports+teams) helpful.

Comment: I would suggest that in this particular case, one could argue for either. I would use whatever seemed right in the context.

Comment: There is a similar problem (not really a problem) with companies who call themselves things like "Dream Technologies"; despite the plural in the name, it is still a single entity and so "Dream Technologies is ..." would be appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The singular use of *archives* is quite grammatical in that it is in use by a respectable organization, and that a distinction may be made between it and the singular *archive* as noted by a commenter on [this Language Log post](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=484):

> This problem crops up with the technical use of "an archives." Among librarians, archivists and historians, the term "an archives" refers specifically to the repository in which papers are housed, not generally to the papers themselves. "An archive" means a single set of papers: "An archive of committee papers." There is some drift between uses and I imagine the singular "archives" will eventually fall out of use altogether, especially as copy editors and people like that are always trying to correct it.

This corresponds to the National Archives' own [definition](https://www.archives.gov/about/info/whats-an-archives.html):

> An archives is a place where people can go to gather firsthand facts,
> data, and evidence from letters, reports, notes, memos, photographs,
> and other primary sources.

The above mentioned Language Log post itself concerned the similar case of *a chambers* meaning *a law practice*, three instances of which may be found in the Hansard Corpus (British Parliament).

> The Terrell plan has been advocated for some years now: It has been
> revived again by Mr: Edward Terrell, who is a Queen's Counsel,
> Recorder of Newbury, 1473 author of a book on running-down cases, and
> is, I gather, head of **a chambers** which has great experience of
> motoring cases of all kinds (Mr Roger Cooke, 1966)
>
> Lord Gifford My Lords, for the past 15 years I have had the honour to
> be head of **a chambers** of barristers, which is unusual in two respects
> which are relevant to this debate (1989)
>
> I come from **a chambers** that specialises partly in competition law (Sir
> Nicholas Lyell, 1998)

Comment: I came so close to downvoting this as yet another answer to yet another hot-potato  question about which agreement should prevail, notional or formal. But your research shows that 'archives' to a certain degree and 'chambers' certainly should be considered separately from say 'Microsoft/the BBC is/are' and 'NASA is/are'.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it matter that the full name of the agency is the National Archives and Records Administration?

Yes. The subject is that particular administration, and that would make it singular, even if you abbreviated it.

If, however, you were talking about the actual, physical National Archives in Washington DC, (which NARA *administers* :) ), then you are talking about a plural subject.